# How do i strip html tags with php on textarea?

Tags: php, html, validation

I am trying to remove tags from a textarea.

I open a html page in a textarea successfully using curl from json data. I removed html tags with php function(strip_tags) but on textarea there are many spaces . How can i fix this?

```html
<?php
foreach($data as $text){
    if($yazi_id["id"]==$_GET["id"]){
        $text = $text["content"]["rendered"];
        $title = $text ["title"]["rendered"];
        break;
    }
}
$text = strip_tags($text);
$title = strip_tags($title);
?>
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Text</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div><?php echo "<b>".$title."</b>"; ?></div>
    <div class="form-outline">
      <textarea class="form-control" id="textAreaExample1" rows="25" style="width:50%;" ><?php echo $text; ?></textarea>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if this will help?
try trim($text)

Comment: Yeah i did this but $text is actually coming from wordpress rest api. So the text is a post in my website. But the post is printed with html img tag and divs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
foreach($data as $text){
    if($yazi_id["id"]==$_GET["id"]){
        $text = $text["content"]["rendered"];
        $title = $text ["title"]["rendered"];
        break;
    }
}
$text = strip_tags($text);
$title = strip_tags($title);

$stripped = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'), ' ', $text);
?>

<textarea class="form-control" id="textAreaExample1" rows="25" style="width:50%;" ><?php echo $stripped; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: it was really helpful thanks, actually $text is  coming from wordpress rest api. So the text is a post in my website. But the post is printed with html img tag and divs